# Reason for fluid rotating with the container

Tags: fluid-statics, viscosity

When a container filled with liquid is rotated with constant angular velocity the surface of liquid becomes paraboloid in shape, but when we say fluid is ideal we consider fluid to be non viscous, if fluid is non viscous it should remain stationary even though container is rotating. Or even if it is non viscous it will rotate ?

Comment: It is an idealization to make the problem just illustrate the point without adding distracting complexities. Like the massless, frictionless pulleys found in so many high school classrooms.

Comment: The liquid would not budge (even at the contact with the container) if the liquid is inviscid.

Answer (score 1):

The [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) is a property of the fluid:

> The viscosity of a fluid is a measure of its resistance to deformation at a given rate. For liquids, it corresponds to the informal concept of "thickness": for example, syrup has a higher viscosity than water.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity)

.......

> A fluid that has no resistance to shear stress is known as an ideal or inviscid fluid. *Zero viscosity is observed only at very low temperatures* in superfluids. Otherwise, the second law of thermodynamics requires all fluids to have positive viscosity;[2][3] such fluids are technically said to be viscous or viscid

italics mine

To get superluids needs complicated devises around the fluid to keep the temperature low, so your thought experiment is really only in thought.

For real low viscocity liquids, one has to keep clear that the adhesion to the walls of the container is what is important if the container starts rotating. The first layer will start moving, acquiring angular momentum and momentum by the surface tension between liquid and wall. How fast this will affect the bulk will depend on viscocity but eventually, even for a gas, there will be a turbulence to the bulk.

In your thought experiment, I expect with zero viscosity the container would move around the liquid , the first layer of the liquid going around on the container.